# Can storing 300k files in one folder cause problems?

Tags: macos, wget, hfs, web-crawler

I'm crawling a large website (over 200k pages) using wget (is there a better tool btw?). Wget is saving all the files to one directory.

The partition is HFS (I think), will it cause problems if I have all the files in one dir? Assuming I will access all of them only from the console (I know Finder has problems with dirs>5k files).

Or is there perhaps a way to create a micro-partition that would be compressed and would allow for a fast, optimized access to this amount of files?

Comment: What flags are you using with wget?

Comment: @Matt: -np, why do you ask?

Comment: I usually specify -m - it keeps the file tree structure for me then - I don't know the layout of the site you're scraping, but that might reduce the number of files in each directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the feasibility of the underlying file-system, you REALLY should NEVER store that many files in one directory.  When it comes time to browse the contents of that directory, you'll quickly discover that there is a HUGE amount of lag while the OS tries to build the file listing and such.  It really puts a significant amount of strain on the system.

Most tools out there that do any sort of "web archiving" will usually build a directory structure similar to the website's layout.  Nearly all websites do not base all their contents off of the root directory... i.e. mydomain.com/document-1 ... they will have some logistics behind it all that split it up into several paths (for a variety of reasons) i.e. images go in mydomain.com/images and stuff about goldfish are in mydomain.com/goldfish/ etc...

There are several tools out there that can & will build this sort of directory structure for you.  even wget has options to download an entire site.  Personally, I've used "[httrack](http://www.httrack.com/)" in the past, and it worked quite well.  There are also command-line options for wget to download an entire site as well.  Look at the -r (recursive) option.  Just make sure you setup your domain list so you don't download links infinitely across multiple sites.  Best do some reading-up on the [wget man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wget).

Comment: Depends what you use to browse the directories. Any gui client will probably be bad(TM) but I'm happy on linux in a bash shell.

Comment: @PriceChild I would agree... except it's not only GUIs... typically there are cron jobs that periodically run things like updatedb and using ftp/sftp/etc... can also really ramp up the amount of resources unnecessarily needed.  It's amazing how much can be saved by simply splitting up a directory structure.  Keep in mind... I did use a lot of *should* (TM) in this post.  There are extenuating circumstances of course... but this is merely advise with an alternative solution.

Comment: any suggestions on what to use instead? I'd like to have a quick&easy access to the files from console (I plan to run regexpes and such on them) - I don't want to split the files into dirs because writing shell scripts that would analyse all the files would be a pain then.

Comment: 1 word.  egrep.  Nearly all *nix tools have a recursive option to search all directories below a target... egrep -R some_word /some/path would be able to search through every directory for "some_word" and return the appropriate results.  quick & easy are typically antonyms.  It can be quick, but difficult to work with --==OR==-- easy but slow.  It would help to know more about what it is exactly you're trying to accomplish.  Perhaps a better option would be to throw the contents into an indexed database rather than using raw-files...

Comment: You're right, egrep is what I need. Thanks, I will do as you say :)

Answer (score -1):

[Wikipedia](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Hierarchical_File_System) states that HFS has a file limit of 65535. So if your partition is indeed HFS, you'll hit that.

---

From Wikipedia:

> Additionally, the limit of 65,535
>   allocation blocks resulted in **files
>   having a "minimum" size equivalent
>   1/65,535th the size of the disk. Thus,
>   any given volume, no matter its size,
>   could only store a maximum of 65,535
>   files.** Moreover, any file would be
>   allocated more space than it actually
>   needed, up to the allocation block
>   size. When disks were small, this was
>   of little consequence, because the
>   individual allocation block size was
>   trivial, but as disks started to
>   approach the 1 GB mark, the smallest
>   amount of space that any file could
>   occupy (a single allocation block)
>   became excessively large, wasting
>   significant amounts of disk space. For
>   example, on a 1 GB disk, the
>   allocation block size under HFS is 16
>   KB, so even a 1 byte file would take
>   up 16 KB of disk space. This situation
>   was less of a problem for users having
>   large files (such as pictures,
>   databases or audio) because these
>   larger files wasted less space as a
>   percentage of their file size. Users
>   with many small files, on the other
>   hand, could lose a copious amount of
>   space due to large allocation block
>   size. This made partitioning disks
>   into smaller logical volumes very
>   appealing for Mac users, because small
>   documents stored on a smaller volume
>   would take up much less space than if
>   they resided on a large partition. The
>   same problem existed in the FAT16 file
>   system.

Comment: I believe this depends on the version of Mac OS that is being used. I think OS X (all versions) use a new partitioning system that mitigates this issue.

Comment: Are you perhaps referring to [HFS+](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/HFS_Plus)? That has a max file count in the thousands of millions.

Comment: Yep, you got me, I was too lazy to look it up. That'll teach me.

Comment: I'd *probably* be willing to bet 50p Merlin is using HFS+ rather than HFS though... :-)

Comment: the drive is 300GB, and was formatted recently, so it's most probably HFS+ :)